# yui image popup

Tags: popup, yui

I cannot believe this question has not been asked before! Maybe I do not understand YUI...  I have a client that uses the YUI library on their site. I do not want to load additional libraries (i.e. jquery) I know little about YIU but I thought it was similar in purpose to jquery. (I getting to the question, it is jut that I have posted elsewhere and the answers is "use jquery", or "why do you want to do this in YUI" instead of answering the question)

Sooo... I want to load a small image and pop up a modal dialog with a large version when that image is clicked... I want to use YIU.  Please someone just tell me if this can be done or not, and if it can..please point me to a tut, or at least to where to look in the YUI API.

Thank yo

Comment: @jshirley's answer is correct. You may also want to look at the YUI Lightbox Gallery module: http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/lightbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using YUI 3, you should be using the Y.Panel for this. It's quite simple to use this widget.

Here is a complete working example for this: http://jsbin.com/uxalec/1/edit

The docs for Y.Panel are available at http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/panel/dialog.html

Comment: You may want to call align() after the image loads (and possibly a few milliseconds after that).

Comment: That's a very good point. The other thing you can do is prefetch the images. In any case, it's worth reading the docs for the ImageLoader at http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/imageloader/

Comment: Thank you, for pointing me in the right direction jshirley (more than that...fantastic sample code!) this is exactly what I assumed could be done.